# how to add spacing between row and columns in FlowLayout?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, flowlayout, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm migrating `FlowLayout` from the accompanist library with the native compose v1.4.0.
To give spacing between columns and rows we had `FlowCrossAxisAlignment` and `FlowMainAxisAlignment`, however now this approach is not available, on the vertical axis in the new api of `FlowRow` we can use `Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)` but there is nothing similar for the other axis, the solution they give is to put bottom padding on each element but that is also applied for the last row. Is there a solution for this?

Issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268365538

This is my code and the result:

```
FlowRow(modifier = modifier.background(color =Color.Blue), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
            chips.forEach { chip ->
                Chip(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Cyan).padding(bottom = 16.dp),
                    label = chip.label
                )
            }
        }
```

[image]

As you can see in the bottom a cyan padding is generated and that is what I want to avoid

EDIT: it seems that the proposal in the issue report has been accepted and they will add the functionality in the next versions.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like support for this was recently added:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268365538

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2478295

However, I don't think it's actually in a released version yet. It looks like it was merged a few days after the March '23 Jetpack Compose update, and I don't think there has been a new version released since then. Good news is, this functionality should be available in the next release.

EDIT: As another answer states, this functionality is available in androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout. Which, as of the time of this comment, is in version beta02. so adding `implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.5.0-beta02"` to your `build.gradle` will make `verticalArrangement` available for a `FlowRow`. I tested this, and it does work.

Comment: I was stuck at the same issue and saw your answer one hour after its submission. It saved me some time. Thank you and let us all be thankful of Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a solution to this issue. You can use the Spacer composable to add space between rows in the FlowRow. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

Comment: FlowColumn(
    modifier = modifier.background(color = Color.Blue),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
) {
    FlowRow(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
        chips.forEach { chip ->
            Chip(
                modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Cyan),
                label = chip.label
            )
        }
    }
    // Add spacer to create space between rows
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
}

Comment: In the modified code, we use a FlowColumn as the parent composable of FlowRow to control the vertical arrangement. Then, we set the verticalArrangement parameter of FlowColumn to Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp) to add spacing between rows.

Comment: I think you did not understand the problem.  The idea is to remove the padding from the last row.  your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue like below as I'm watting for stable release of `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.5.0`
currently it's in `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.5.0-alpha02`

**Note:** This is a temporary solution Google has already solved this issue in `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.5.0-alpha02` You can use it if you don't mind using an **alpha** versions in your project.

```
@Composable
fun FilterChips(data: String) = Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp)) {
      Text(
          text = data,
          style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
          color = Color.Black,
          modifier = Modifier
              .background(Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
              .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
      )
}



@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun Preview() {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            val list = listOf(
                "2/2/2022",
                "1/1/2023",
            )
            FlowRow(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
            ) {
                list.forEach {
                    FilterChips(it)
                }
            }
        }
}
```